Битовые операции,с двумя числами.C#
Задание:написать программу на c#, которая позволит ввести два целых числа с
клавиатуры по отдельности(сначала первое,затем второе), найти и вывести на дисплей их произведение, используя битовые
операции сделать в нем, чтобы 7, 5 и 3 биты были равны 0, а остальные
сохранили свои значения, вывести результат
Правильно ли я делаю?
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n1;
        int n2;

        Console.Write("Введите первое число: ");
        n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите второе число: ");
        n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int pr = n1 * n2;

        
        pr &= ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 3));

        Console.WriteLine("Результат: " + pr);
    }
}


Проверьте на числе pr=255. И нужно знать, как ваши преподы нумеруют биты - с нуля или с единицы

выводит просто результат умножения

ОМГ. Введите 15 и 17

И все таки я делаю верно или нет?Где я ошибся если да?

Верно (если младший бит считается нулевым). Я же вам дал совет, как проверить  - число из одних единиц использовать. И можно результат вывести как бинарную строку Convert.ToString(pr, 2)

я пытаюсь вывести результат как вы и подсказали но получается вообще 87

int n1;
int n2;
        Console.Write("Введите первое число: ");
        n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите второе число: ");
        n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int pr = n1 * n2;

        Convert.ToString(pr, 2);
        pr &= ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 3));
        

        Console.WriteLine(pr);


я сделал по другому,но он выводит число в двоичной системе без изменений.
int product = num1 * num2;
Console.WriteLine($"The modified product of {num1} and {num2} is {product}");
int value = product;
String binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
product &= ~(1 << 7) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 3);
Console.WriteLine(binary);

https://ideone.com/4QpNAu

спасибо большое,мозг кипит уже ничего не соображаю ,на примере сейчас увидел что все было легче.Благодарю

Так даже нагляднее:  int n1 = 7;        int n2 = 73;

попробовал,действительно!

Да, делаете правильно, если ваши преподаватели считают биты, начиная с нулевого (младший) - бывает, что младший называют первый.
Вот как можно проверить - сделать произведение чисел таким, чтобы его битовое представление содержало только единицы (числа вида 2^k-1), и выполнить обнуление нужных битов. Пример для 0b111111111=511=7*73:
    int n1 = 7;
    int n2 = 73;
 
    int pr = n1 * n2;
 
    Console.WriteLine("Произведение: " + pr + " Binary: " + Convert.ToString(pr, 2));
 
    pr &= ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 5) | (1 << 3));
 
    Console.WriteLine("Результат   : " + pr + " Binary: " + Convert.ToString(pr, 2));

Выдача:
Произведение: 511 Binary: 111111111
Результат   : 343 Binary: 101010111

